# Chrome, standard timeout?

Tags: google-chrome, timeout

What is the standard (out of the box) timeout for Chrome?
How do I change the timeout settings and have a different timeout for developers and a standard users of my service?

Comment: I wonder where is the answer to first part of the question in that so called duplicate question... `What is the standard (out of the box) timeout for Chrome? `

Answer (score 9):

#### What is the standard (out of the box) timeout for Chrome?

> You can see the default value in Chrome in this [link](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/socket/client_socket_pool.cc?sq=package:chromium&l=25)
>
> ```
> int64_t g_used_idle_socket_timeout_s = 300 // 5 minutes
> ```

Source [Where can I find the default timeout settings for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342310/where-can-i-find-the-default-timeout-settings-for-all-browsers)

---

#### How do I change the timeout settings and have a different timeout for developers and a standard users of my service?

You can't.

> In Chrome, as far as I know, there isn't an easy way (as Firefox do) to change the timeout value.

Source [Where can I find the default timeout settings for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342310/where-can-i-find-the-default-timeout-settings-for-all-browsers)