# chromium: "stop loading this page" button erases URL from URL bar

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium

When I type URL into chromium URL bar, ie `http://10.10.10.3:80` and the server is currently unreachable, when I wand chromium to stop trying to load, and I press the "stop loading this page" button, the URL disappears. This is evil!

Lets say, I have the port wrong, so I want to try again with another port. I have to type the whole URL again.

When I press the "stop loading this page" button, the URL should stay there as I typed it, so that I can correct it.

Instead, it is replaced by the "last successful URL" that was there before.

is there a way to fix this evil feature?

Comment: If you want to fix it, you may have to manually patch the source code and recompile, each update. To avoid this behavior it is enough you open a new page or a new tab before start to write the URL.  So, no page preloaded no *evil* behavior (that BTW avoids scams).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is by design and a few years ago the developers of all browsers
made a big effort to make it impossible to have a page displayed with the
wrong URL.
This was actually possible before, until this technique started being used by malware.

The behavior you are asking for is a security hole. If it was possible to
display a page with the wrong URL, an attacker could display the URL of
your bank together with his own page, this way getting you to type in your
account number and password, then emptying all your accounts.
This did actually happen, until this loophole was closed.

Showing a wrong URL is only possible on the new-tab page, where it happens
automatically.
The reason it works here is that there is no real page being displayed,
so there is no security reason not to display the entered (wrong) URL.

This behavior is not particular to Chromium. Every browser I have encountered
does exactly the same, as this is the secure thing to do.

In addition, browser developers even made it impossible for a thrown dialog to
obscure the address bar, since this technique was immediately used by attackers
when it became impossible to modify the URL itself, to mimic a false
address bar.

The only solution I can offer is to copy a long typed URL before hitting
<kbd>Enter</kbd>, and this is what I already do.
You should get into the habit of doing
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>
before, just in case.

---

Here is how an attacker can use the option you ask for to get your bank login:

- The attacker's add-on or JavaScript script throws up his own website
  `attacker.com/exploit` which looks exactly like your bank, except that
  the address bar gives it away.
- The attacker would like to have your bank's URL or something very similar
  in the address bar, but can't, since all APIs that do so were carefully
  weeded out by the developers.
- The attacker then invokes a website with a URL that is very similar,
  or that whose name is displayed exactly the same (Unicode tricks),
  as your bank's URL.
- This website does not exist, but the wrong URL will stay in the address bar.
  Together with the displayed page, this would look like you are really
  in your bank's site.
- You do the login, and a few seconds later, all your bank accounts
  have been emptied out. Bye bye all your savings.
  The bank rightfully claims that this is your fault and returns nothing.

Comment: thank you for the explanation and context. But, aren't we mixing two different things here? I am not asking for one URL to be displayed, and another to be actually loaded. That would indeed be security problem. I am asking for URL to stay in the URL bar, even if the server is not responding. How does that have any implications for security? I am not trying to fake anything.

Comment: *You* are not trying to fake anything, but if this was possible then a malware add-on or JavaScript could do the same thing. The developers have closed off all and every means of doing that, in order to protect the users.

Comment: still does not make sense to me, but nevermind. If the browser behaved as I describe, I don't see any security problem. If site is not loading, URL bar should show the URL, and page should be blank. No way to exploit this logical behavior.

Comment: I can see many ways of exploiting such behavior, as did several malware authors. You may search it out.

Comment: I added how to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I see now where our misunderstanding is coming from: `This website does not exist, but the wrong URL will stay in the address bar. Together with the displayed page`. The behavior I am describing should display blank page, or page not found, or anything. But not the previous page.

Comment: You could try to write an add-on that intercepts the condition of page-not-found and  displays an empty page, except that ... the page would be displayed with its own URL and not with your wrong URL. The add-on would need to capture the wrong URL and *incorporate it* into the new page in a way that you may copy it, or fix it and press a Submit button. I don't really know how many other browser safeguards you may encounter on the way, but you would need guru-level knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible because of how the web traffic works, each request have/need a resulting status and can not be stateless this is why chromium remove the address you were trying to connect to (other than the security aspect of such thing).

When you request a connection to a domain/ip, the result can be for instance: 200 (OK page load), 404 (not found), 408 (timeout) etc. when you cancel your request before reaching a state, it's obvious that the browser does not display any result/url because of the cancel action and there is no HTTP state XXX code that is meant for "cancelled request" ([list of http requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)).

*Impossible is nothing, three possible ways of resolving this issue:*

- Create an extension for the matter
- Patch to chromium to add an `xxx` state (non RFC) for cancelled requests (note that chromium require a very long time to build)
- Decrease the default `timeout` (408), this is [not possible on chromium without patching it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39751124/increase-timeout-limit-in-google-chrome), it is discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/633648/how-can-i-change-the-default-website-connection-timeout-in-chrome) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1012176/chrome-standard-timeout) as well.

  - Acknowledge that this may introduce other non desired effect like timing-out slow sites.
  - Also note that this is doable on Firefox with `network.http.connection-timeout` setting.

Comment: Wrong, wrong, wrong, this has nothing to do with HTTP codes and everything to do with security. Read my answer.

Comment: @harrymc Yes, i know there were effort to avoid malware's URLs masking but this is not what the OP is asking, basically he cancel a web request before it get any state, the browser then remove the URL for two reasons, 1 is security indeed, but 2 it's because the request is not accomplished and does not have any state to be displayed, note that this does not work for new tab either.

Comment: It works for new tab in my case; and you have it reversed: The error code triggers the security measure.

Answer (score 1):

#### Good Practice

There is a simple way to avoid the annoiance,
as simple as to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd>:
open a new tab or a new window and to write there the new URL.

In case of a manually interruption there is no preloaded page and the URL will be not deleted from the bar.

#### Fix

If you want to fix it, you may have to manually patch the source code and recompile it, for each update.

You may find useful to download the source code, write a fork and apply the differences to each of the following updated version. But remember that the present behavior is made to avoid attempts of scam... so the best practice above.

#### Final remarks (Tl;dr)

I know it often ends up being easier to change our behavior than to find the right program setting... and it should not be so...

The fact is that, this time, there is a serious reason that suggests that we change our behavior and that it can be considered good practice.

In this case the suggestion is not to find a way to change the behavior of the program, no matters how, but to change (by pressing only two keys) our behavior in order to avoid potential risks.